# Use magick to compress duplicate images

Tags: imagemagick

I want to play 3 pictures repeatedly for 10 times in a gif. How do I compress the size of gif using magick?
`convert -delay 100 -coalesce -layers Optimize 0[123].png 0[123].png 0[123].png 0[123].png 0[123].png 0[123].png 0[123].png 0[123].png 0[123].png 0[123].png out.gif`
The gif generated by the above code does not seem to compress the repeating frame, just simply superimpose the image.
The `-loop` option cannot be used because the playback device can only play gif once.

Comment: try `convert -delay 100 0[123].png -duplicate 9 -layers RemoveDups out.gif`. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_opt/#optframe